# iOS MultiTasking is not working

Tags: ios, ios5, multitasking, background-process

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
device.batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
    [self beingBackgroundUpdateTask];
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification" object:device];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification" object:device];
[self currentBatteryState];


}


- (void) beingBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    self->backgroundUpdateTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
}


- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self->backgroundUpdateTask];
    self->backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

For some reason, the notification's are not being observed. Am i doing something wrong? I want to observe for unto 10 minutes when unplugged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `endBackgroundUpdateTask` in your `buttonPressed:` method, since that cancels your background task. Try removing this code:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
}
```

Also, you should pass the `UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification` constant to the "name" parameter, not the string. It should look like this (note the lack of double quotes):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:device];
```

(It's also possible that UIDevice simply doesn't send those notifications in the background.)

Comment: How can I find out for sure if UIDevice does send notifications in the background?

Comment: I would try fixing those two things I suggested first and then testing to see if those notifications arrive while in the background.

Comment: I modified the code as per your suggestions. It didnt appear to work

Comment: Would you post updated code? And perhaps add some logging to you beingBackgroundUpdateTask, endBackgroundUpdateTask, and batteryChanged: methods?

Comment: I ran the debugger and I did see it enter those methods. But once unplugged (iPhone), it doesn't do what it's suppose to

Comment: Are you running your app from Xcode? If you are, it will kill the app when you un-plug it from your computer. Do you get the battery notifications when it's still plugged in?

Comment: Yes I am getting the battery notification while plugged in. Yes I am using the latest release of Xcode on 10.7

Comment: Try starting the app when not plugged in.

Comment: When the app starts without being plugged in. It behaves as expected. Is battery monitoring not possible while app is in background?

Comment: Does it work when in the background if you start it unplugged?

Comment: I play an MP3 sound effect when it's unplugged. When in the foreground, the app changes the UILabel and plays a sound. When in the background, nothing happens

Comment: That's probably a separate issue: you can't play a sound like that in the background; you might want to look into background audio. You could use logging to confirm that the battery notifications are actually being delivered in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the applicable backgrounding code to your AppDelegate? Here are backgrounding [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) in the iOS Programming Guide

Comment: I saw the documentation and didn't understand it. What do I do in my AppDelegate and how do I link it to the method in my ViewController?